# How Can Override Block (\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php)

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Maxime\Helloworld\Block\Rewrite\Product\Selectoption" />
</config>
```

```
<?php
namespace Maxime\Helloworld\Block\Rewrite\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Selectoption extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{

    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        $this->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select'
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select',
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('fdhfgdhfghdfg'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    falsehh
                );
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                    ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
                );
            }
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
        ) {
            $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                            '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '" class="' .
                            $class .
                            ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            ']"' .
                            ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                            ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                            ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '"><span>' .
                            __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ]
                );

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
                }

                $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                    $require .
                    '">' .
                    '<input type="' .
                    $type .
                    '" class="' .
                    $class .
                    ' ' .
                    $require .
                    ' product-custom-option"' .
                    ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                    ' name="options[' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    ']' .
                    $arraySign .
                    '" id="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '" value="' .
                    $htmlValue .
                    '" ' .
                    $checked .
                    ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                    ' price="' .
                    $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                    '" />' .
                    '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '"><span>' .
                    $_value->getTitle() .
                    '</span> ' .
                    $priceStr .
                    '</label>';
                $selectHtml .= '</div>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the main purpose is to change the html content of the output in \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php, you can try via virtualType.

```
<virtualType name="customCheckable" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\CheckableFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Checkable</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="checkableFactory" xsi:type="object">customCheckable</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

instanceName is the variable used in Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\CheckableFactory

customCheckable can be any name

checkableFactory is the variable used in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Checkable extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Checkable
{
    /**
     * Checkable constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $pricingHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $pricingHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $pricingHelper, $catalogData, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::product/composite/fieldset/options/view/checkable.phtml';

    /**
     * @return bool|string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getCustomMethod()
    {
        return 'Sample Value';
    }
}
```

in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/composite/fieldset/options/view/checkable.phtml call the function getCustomMethod()

```
<?= $block->getCustomMethod()?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the plugin for this

Please follow  then blog as plug in reference

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html
https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/create-a-magento-2-plugin/
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-use-plugins/
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

For You case

***di.xml should contain below code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld_Plugin_Post" sortOrder="10" 
            type="[Vendorname]\[Modulename]\Plugin\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

***And plugin class: [Vendorname][Modulename]\Plugin\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select***

```
namespace [Vendorname]\[Modulename]\Plugin\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select {

    public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)
    {
        // modify code at $result
        return $result; 
    }
    public function beforeGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)
    {
        // modify code at $result
        return $result; 
    }
     public function aroundGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select  $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
       // change here
        $returnValue = $proceed();
        if ($returnValue) {
           //chnages
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

use before, after and around method  as per as your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Above answers helped me but it did not work for me as it is. 
This is what I did to override block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

**File - [Vendor][Module]\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select">
    <plugin name="[Vendor]_[Module]_select" sortOrder="10"
            type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"/>
</type>
```

**File - [Vendor][Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions
{

 public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)
 {
    $_option = $subject->getOption();
    $configValue = $subject->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
    $store = $subject->getProduct()->getStore();

    $subject->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
    // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

    if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
        $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
    ) {
        $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';

        $extraParams = '';
        $select = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
            ]
        );
        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
            // Code changes start
            if($_option->getIsSize()){
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select a Size'));
            }
            else if($_option->getIsCut()){
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select a Cut'));
            }
            else{
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select an Option'));
            }
            // Code changes end
        } else {
            $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . '][]');
            $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
        }
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                [
                    'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                ],
                false
            );
            $select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                ['price' => $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
            );
        }
        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
            $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
        }
        if (!$subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
            $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
        }
        $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
        $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

        if ($configValue) {
            $select->setValue($configValue);
        }

        return $select->getHtml();
    }

    if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
        $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
    ) {
        $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
        $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
        $arraySign = '';
        switch ($_option->getType()) {
            case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                $type = 'radio';
                $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                    $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                        '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        '" class="' .
                        $class .
                        ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        ']"' .
                        ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                        ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                        ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        '"><span>' .
                        __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                }
                break;
            case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                $type = 'checkbox';
                $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                $arraySign = '[]';
                break;
        }
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $count++;

            $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                [
                    'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                ]
            );

            $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
            if ($arraySign) {
                $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
            } else {
                $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
            }

            $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
            if ($arraySign) {
                $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
            }

            $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                $require .
                '">' .
                '<input type="' .
                $type .
                '" class="' .
                $class .
                ' ' .
                $require .
                ' product-custom-option"' .
                ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                ' name="options[' .
                $_option->getId() .
                ']' .
                $arraySign .
                '" id="options_' .
                $_option->getId() .
                '_' .
                $count .
                '" value="' .
                $htmlValue .
                '" ' .
                $checked .
                ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                ' price="' .
                $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                '" />' .
                '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                $_option->getId() .
                '_' .
                $count .
                '"><span>' .
                $_value->getTitle() .
                '</span> ' .
                $priceStr .
                '</label>';
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';
        }
        $selectHtml .= '</div>';

        return $selectHtml;
    }
 }
}
```

***Important things to note here -***

```
After copying `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php` to [`Vendor][Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php`, you must do following.

1. Change the namespace to `[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;`
2. Replace `public function getValuesHtml()` to `public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)`
3. Replace `$this` to `$subject`
```

Hope this helps.